# Chi-squared test property

Tags: probability

I have got the following:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \frac{O_i - N p_i }{N p_i + (1-p_i)} \sim \chi^2_{k-1} $$

How to prove that $$\sum_{i=1}^{k} \frac{O_i - N p_i }{N p_i} \sim \chi^2_{k-1} $$?

Where:

$O_i$ is the number of observations in the $i$ interval.
$p_i$ is the probability for choice the $i$ interval.
$N$ the number of samples

Comment: Could you explain what each of the terms mean?